# stdout & stderr of bunch of lines to /dev/null

Tags: bash, redirect, stdout

Sorry, if the question has been asked previously, or is simple. I googled a bit and couldn't find the answer, and I a novice.

I usually use `&>/dev/null` to redirect stdout and stderr for each command that I have to.
In one of my codes, I have to do this for 10 consecutive commands which is ugly :)

```
   Command 1 &>/dev/null
   Command 2 &>/dev/null
   .
   .
   .
   Command 10 &>/dev/null
```

Is there anyway to do this procedure for all of them at once; for example

```
   Command 1 
   Command 2 
   .
   .
   .
   Command 10 
   **Redirect all of them together**
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @BroSlow's answer best. Another way to redirect stdout and stderr

```
echo before

# turn off stdout and stderr
# (but save their currect locations first)
exec 3>&1 1>/dev/null
exec 4>&2 2>/dev/null

echo no
echo error >&2
echo output

# restore stdout and stderr
# and close the temp file descriptors
exec 1>&3 3>&-
exec 2>&4 4>&-

echo after
echo after error >&2
```

You'll see the "before" and "after" stuff, but not the output in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

Just surround them with braces

```
{
  Command 1
  Command 2
  .
  .
  .
  Command 10
} &>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the number after command is the parameter for command or file descriptor numbers? Can you explain?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in {1..10}
do
  command $i &>/dev/null
done
```